# oledb connection error loading datatable but only on one machine

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb

I'm at a loss. I have this code which runs fine on my machine and loads a csv to a datatable:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, string sheetname, string header)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var myFile = directory.GetFiles().Where(x => x.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(sheetname.ToLowerInvariant())).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First().Name;
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + myfile+ "]";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
              @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path +
              ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

this works fine on my machine. On a different machine it does not though. I googled and checked we have the identical version of MSJet40.dll in the same place, we are both on 64bit machines but on the machine where it doesn't work I don't have Visual studio so I can't debug.

Comment: When you say "it does not [work]", how is it failing?  Throwing an error?  Not producing any results?

Comment: Have you verified that you can access the directory named in `path` from the other machine, and that the file you expect to find is there?

Comment: the user can open the file manually, I put a try catch around for it to not crash but it comes back empty

Comment: Your `try..catch` does something with the error, yes?  So if it were throwing one, you'd know?

Comment: yes, plus it runs fine on my machine

Comment: Are you getting a null `DataTable`?  Or an empty `DataTable`?